# Angular HttpClient interceptors complete callback not invoking for browser status code 304

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-http-interceptors, angular-httpclient

Angular HttpClient interceptors are not working with status code 304. I'm using interceptor to show loading bar.

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> 
    {            
        console.log('started');
        // start loading bar
        return next.handle(req).do((event) => {
            // play with event
            console.log(event);
        }, (err) => {
            // play with error
            console.log('error');
            // stop loading bar 
        }, () => {
            console.log('completed');
            // stop loading bar 
        });
    }
}
```

For all the requests (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE) to my backend it's working perfect but while loading language file "complete" call back is not invoking.

Also I can see 304 status code in browser but angular http response status code is 200.

Is there a reason why complete callback is not invoking? Am I doing something wrong here?

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you tried the same in incognito mode?

Comment: @DeepakJha yes I tried. Same 304 status code and complete call back is not invoking

Comment: I don't know about you but mine does fire up: http://oi66.tinypic.com/vp9843.jpg

Comment: How did you resolve this? I am having the same issue.